# Flutter: Image over Image, show upper image partially as value provided (e.g. 1 to 10)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-image

I have an image view, that show two images (one over other). (I achieved using Stack)

Now, Image on the back will remain static. (This is done)

Image on the top will be reveal from bottom right. (problem I am asking for)

like below screenshot.

[image]

if you notice in the screenshot, how that emoji is revealing from bottom right.

Revealing have 10 different steps (e.g. 1 means fully show, 5 means half, 10 means totally hidden likewise)

How can I achieve this in flutter Dart?

Edit:

Now I have problem of image masking. (see below screenshot)

[image]

Comment: there is a width parameter inside Postioned widget for stack. Or use left, right params of Postioned widget.

Comment: comment if you need an example code.

Comment: yes please, if you can provide example code would be great.

Comment: its a bit difficult to understand your question, if you have 10 different steps, you can create an array with your 10 images url (or asset path), and then depending on the step index display the image. like List<String> image;     int _step = 0;      return Container(... src: image[_step]  ...;     but I am not sure that I understood correctly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @RasheshBosamiya sure

Comment: creating 10 images array is not ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  int step = 5;
  int maxStep = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Img.back(),
              Positioned(
                child: Img.front(),
                top: step * 200 / maxStep,
                left: step * 200 / maxStep,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Img extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color fill;

  Img.back([this.fill = Colors.green]);

  Img.front([this.fill = Colors.blue]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      color: fill,
    );
  }
}
```

---

Dartpad does not support local Image so I used a simple container, but the concept is same.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I checked your solution. It is working 85%

Comment: Now the problem I am having is of image masking, image on the back.

Comment: Though your solution is 100 percent correct

Comment: top image must have transparent parts for masking to work properly.

Comment: photoshop. top image should have only the guy in the image surrounded by transparent pixel background.

Comment: yes, I back image is already png & having transparent background.

Comment: can you post links to both the images?

Comment: I have updated my question, see image there

Comment: just use a clipoval widget or a cliprrect over the stack and set the size

Comment: Thank you brother/sister. I will soon accept your answer.